# How to add values from two buttons to single inputbox?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Assume that I have two buttons with the values `'abc'` and `'efg'` respectively, and an inputbox.

This is what I want to achieve :

- When I click the button with the value `'abc'` a single time, the value `'a'` gets appended to the inputbox. If I press it two times immediately the value suddenly changes to `'b'` instead of `'a'`, and when I do it three times it changes to `'c'` instead of `'b'`.
- I should be able to type double `'a'`'s (or any of `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`) by waiting some time between button clicks on button `'abc'`. For instance : I first click button `'abc'`, then `'a'` gets into the inputbox, I wait for a short time and clicks one more time to get another `'a'`.
- I want the same functionality with all the buttons (`'abc'` and `'efg'`).

I have linked sample expected output image.

View this **[jsfiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/37jnz6eu/)**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="btnTxt[btnarr]">
    <button ng-modle="btnarr" ng-Click="change()">abc</button>
</div>
```

Expected output:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ae91f828/1/

Comment: @dfsq like this  http://i.stack.imgur.com/46jpu.png , http://jsfiddle.net/37jnz6eu/

Comment: Well then you need to explain better. You said *singleclick = a, doubleclick = b, tripleclick = c*.. How is that about `aebfcg`?

Comment: @dtfg its like T9 typing, check out the code via jsfiddle, somehow i made it toggle 'a','b','c','1'. On one click I should get the first letter, on double click I should get the second letter, and on click 3 times I should get the third letter

Comment: the problem is i couldn't add the next value to the same input box

Comment: So basically you want it to toggle a/b/c on the first button but when you select the second button you want it to toggle e/f/g while keeping the first selected character in the input?

Comment: You should use a timer to determine whether to change the last character in the input or add a new one. That way if you click two times and writes a "b" and then you want to add an "a", you just wait a second or two and the timer by then will have ended and the script would add another char.

Comment: @NewToJS exactly! that is what am looking for, could you explain how to do? Basically am trying to do is T9 typing keyboard in JavaScript.

Comment: @pinx0 could you explain with a sample code?

Comment: @JaganG, this is too broad of a question. Break it down. Do you know how to add values of multiples buttons without the single/double/triple click? Do you know how to build custom input controls without adding them together? Do you know how to detect a double click from a single click, or a triple from a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried one without using built-in timer functions, and checking it manually.

[Solution at Pastebin : pastebin.com/vHF517FN](http://pastebin.com/vHF517FN)

See if it's good enough for you. Btw, I didn't really refactor much, will do it if you are satisfied with this (I'm also new to js -_-).

**EDIT**

Refactored anyway.

[Refactored Solution at Pastebin : pastebin.com/EnHz2EHK](http://pastebin.com/EnHz2EHK)

**EDIT 2**

Added it to JSFiddle. However, I had to add everything to HTML part to make it work there, moving script to script part isn't working for me (wonder why).

[Solution at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/limekin/q0zL6z80/)

```
<script>
 var prevClick = '!';
 var prevClickTime;
 var clicks = 0;

 function buttonClick(letters) {
    var input = document.getElementById("put");
    var backLetterIndex = (clicks == 0) ? letters.length-1 : clicks - 1;

    if(letters[backLetterIndex] == prevClick) {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();

    if(now - prevClickTime < 500) {
        var val = input.value;
        input.value = val.slice(0, val.length - 1);
    }
    else
        clicks = 0;

    }
    else 
    clicks = 0;

    prevClickTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    prevClick = letters[clicks];
    clicks = (clicks + 1) % letters.length;
    input.value = input.value +  prevClick;
}
</script>

<input id="put" type="text"></input>

<button onClick="buttonClick('abc');">abc</button>
<button onClick="buttonClick('defg');">defg</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I get it, you want to do phone keyboard.
I am not sure what exactly is your question so here I wrote complete example
http://jsfiddle.net/daybda4h/5/

Bacically, I wrote click event listener with timer if click comes within 200ms after another click I count up.

```
    clicks++;
    if(timer) {
         clearTimeout(timer);   
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        timer = null;
        updateInput(clicks, evt.target);
        clicks = 0;
    }, timeout);
```

Then, when no more clicks are comming, I take the final number of clicks, take data attribute of a button that says what letters does it control, and take the letter number according to num of clicks.

to add value to input, you simply take input value and add the same value + some custom string.

```
function updateInput(cl, btn) {
    var input = document.getElementById("test");
    var letters = btn.getAttribute("data-letters").split("");

    input.value = input.value + letters[cl-1];
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem :)